# jQuery Slide-panel with Mouse-out and Off-click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle, panel

I'm trying to make a simple jQuery panel slider and have it basically where I want it minus two features. You can see a version of it at: http://jsfiddle.net/7WArj/

Currently the panel slides down over content and closes when the close button is clicked. The button changes because I want the image that will eventually be the button to point up when open and down when closed.

I would love to add the functionality that when you are no longer hovering over the panel, it times out and slides back up after x seconds.

I would also love to add the functionality that if you click anywhere off the slide-panel it will also trigger the panel sliding up.

I attempted some of this with `.toggle()` and `.bind` but was unable to make it work properly. The menu would randomly slide up and down, etc.

If there is a better way to write my code, as well, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is what you want, the code is commented with what I did:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/jhYWk/

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("div#toppanel").attr('tabindex', -1); //Let the DIV have focus

    jQuery("div#toppanel").blur(function(){
        jQuery("div#panel").animate({height: "0px"}, "fast"); // On blur, hide it
    });

    timerRunning = false;
    jQuery("div#panel").hover(function(){ //on mouse over clear a timeout if it exists
        if (timerRunning) {
            clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
            timerRunning = false;
        }
    },
    function(){ //on mouse out set the timeout
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery("div#panel").animate({height: "0px"}, "fast");
        }, 2000);
        timerRunning = true;
    });

    jQuery('#toppanel').click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation();
     });

    jQuery("div.panel_button").click(function(){
        jQuery("div#panel").focus().animate({ height: "250px" }, "fast");
        jQuery("div.panel_button").toggle()
    }); 

    jQuery("div#hide_button").click(function(){
        jQuery("div#panel").animate({height: "0px"}, "fast"); 
    });
});
```

​

CSS:

```
#toppanel {
    outline: 0; /* Remove yellow outline in Chrome */
    z-index: 25;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#panel {
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    height: 0px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
}
#panel_contents {
    height: 100%;
    width: 603px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.the_content {
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

​

​
HTML: Same

Comment: Looks like exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that there's still some issue with the button down/up states and the menu popping back up really quickly depending on what you do and when you do it

Comment: No problem, but, i've caught two mistakes in the code so far so you should check it. P.S. You don't need to use `jQuery` inside of jQuery defined functions, you can just use `$` as usual even if you have another library that uses it.

Comment: Oh, woops. That happens when you accidentally double-click, I think. Fixed now, the focus function is move from the content to the whole slider.

Comment: If I answered your question please click the checkmark on the left side of my answer, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I appreciate the help. Sorry for the delay on the acceptance, I was out of town.

Answer (score 1):

it works well but I found an issue, if you open it with "Button Down" than mouseout and wait it closes => Fine.

Problem at this point, if you open it again with "Button Down" it closes right away.

If I may, I'm proposing a solution to close while mouseleave so

```
$( "#toppanel" ).mouseleave(
function( event ){
    var container = $( "#panel" );
    if (container.is( ":visible" )){
    $('#panel').delay(1800).slideUp(300);}
});
```